# How to verify that the installation of Apache Server works?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, libraries, x-server, error-handling

- Debian 9.5
- Apache HTTP Server 2.4.34 (httpd)

After installing Apache from the [official page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html) with `sudo make install`, I want to check that the installation works starting the server:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
```

But I get an error

**/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_crypto_init**

Is the error related to the subject of libraries? What could it be?

The configuration that I made during the installation was:

```
$ sh configure --prefix /usr/local/apache2
```

If you need to attach screens, logs or installed libraries update the post to have more details.

---

> SOLUTION

I rebuilt httpd with a prefix of /usr/local

```
$ sh configure --prefix /usr/local
$ sudo make install
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/apachectl -k start
```

I recommend returning to the initial state of the virtual machine, so there are no residual libraries and files.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't user the packaged version of apache via apt?

Comment: I was following a tutorial (subdomain for jira software) which redirected me to a new page with the Apache documentation, and from that page I accessed the download. I did not know I could do it via apt. How should I do it?

Comment: I believe you can do an `apt-get install apache2` to get this installed in Debian. There are many tutorials for this. I'm not versed in Debian but this looks promising - https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/apache-web-server-debian-8/.

Comment: It looks like you have already verified that it does not work.

Comment: Some things to consider: install with `apt-get` (already mentioned), use `stow` to combine self-builds into `/usr/local`, use `docker`, to have a self contained server (May be a newer version, can be from any distro, can be self-built).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor What benefit would it bring me to use Docker instead of VM for Apache?

Comment: Docker is much lighter than VM. Apache will run directly on the kernel. Docker provides easy management of secure namespaces, cgroups, file-system layering, etc. It is not a virtualisation system. Therefore **smaller**: no kernel, and typically only what is needed. **Faster**: no virtualisation over-head. Better supported: more ready made images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the error (probably) relates to libraries. I suspect that since you gave `configure` a prefix of `/usr/local/apache2`, the libraries built for `httpd` ended up in `/usr/local/apache2/lib`, which the dynamic linker doesn’t know about.

There are a number of ways to fix this:

- Use [the package](https://tracker.debian.org/apache2) instead, it will make your life easier in the long run:

  ```
  sudo apt install apache2
  ```

or

- Add `/usr/local/apache2/lib` to the dynamic linker’s configuration; create a file, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/apache2-local.conf`, containing the single line

  ```
  /usr/local/apache2/lib
  ```

  and run `sudo ldconfig`.

or

- Rebuild `httpd` with a prefix of `/usr/local`, so that its binaries end up in `/usr/local/bin` and its libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.

(By the way, you don’t need to run `configure` as root, and you shouldn’t — configure and build as a plain user, and only install as root.)

Comment: The 3rd option works

Comment: What is the difference between using PREFIX = /usr/local or resolving this with a dynamic linker's configuration?

Comment: Setting the prefix to `/usr/local` means that the libraries end up installed in a directory the linker already knows about, so it doesn’t need any configuration. Setting it to `/usr/local/apache2` means that the libraries end up in a directory the linker doesn’t know about, so it needs to be told about it before it can use it.